# Rearrange Firefox toolbars

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I am using Firefox 4, and the one thing which annoys me the most is order of my toolbars. I have tried `Customize` option but it only lets me move items of toolbar and not the whole toolbar itself. Can anybody please help me with repositioning my toolbar orders?

Comment: I too tried this.. unable to reposition. Tried by hiding the toolbars and then disable the hiding. Still they get the same original position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an add on that lets you move toolbars, maybe this helps. It's for 4.08b only, but you can [change these requirements and try to install it anyway](http://pascal.vanhecke.info/2007/10/22/firefox-extension-not-compatible-with-browser-flock-mozilla-seamonkey-version-what-to-do/).

#### [DragNDrop Toolbars](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dragndrop-toolbars/)

> Install this extension, and you will be able to chose the vertical order of your toolbars simply using "Drag and Drop".
>
> You will not be able to merge toolbars, or add one at the bottom of another one.

[image]

Apart from that, maybe this Firefox Help page will help: ["How do I customize the toolbars?"](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/how-do-i-customize-toolbars?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How%20to%20customize%20the%20toolbar)

Comment: URL says:
Service Unavailable

The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.

Comment: now the URL is working, however, the addon Not available for Firefox 4.0.1

Comment: @Mohan Maybe one can change the requirements in the installation file and get it to work anyway, see my edit above.