# Can't get my bookmarks toolbar above another toolbar in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox

Okay, so I have a bookmarks toolbar and a StumbleUpon toolbar. In Firefox 3.6, I had the StumbleUpon bar as the bottom-most toolbar, and the bookmarks toolbar above it.

I'm trying to achieve the same effect in FF4, but it disappears when I try:

Here's what it looks like normally:
[image: Here's what it looks like normally]

When I go into "Customize," the user interface looks like this:
[image: User Interface]

You can see how the SU bar and bookmarks bar have icons for them, and that I should switch them like so:
[image: Switching the icons]

But when I save it (with bookmarks bar above SU bar), the bookmarks bar disappears!
[image: Oh no!]

How can I fix this? I want the SU bar to be my bottommost bar and have the bookmarks toolbar above it. Is it a bug with FF4?

Comment: make sure that you have the bookmarks bar checked, when you right-click on any of the toolbars.

Comment: I definitely do, during all steps.

Comment: can't think of anything else, I have wrested with that Customize thing many times in a number of versions of Firefox, it can be hard to work with at times...Hope you find a solution!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rearrange Firefox toolbars](http://superuser.com/questions/278179/rearrange-firefox-toolbars)

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem for a while on two computers (Currently running FF 7.01, but appeared in earlier versions)

**I solved it by adding a new empty toolbar**. It seems like FF "hides" the first toolbar up under the navigation bar, even though that is probably not the correct description of the problem.

The new empty toolbar seem to push my bookmarks toolbar down so it is visible again.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I got frustrated and placed my bookmarks toolbar under the SU bar and left it.

Some time later, I closed Firefox and then opened it and... somehow, magically, the bookmarks bar was above the SU bar. It hasn't changed since.

<s>It's weird because I did restart Firefox a few times trying this, and eventually just stopped trying. I don't understand it, but I'm glad it happened.</s>

I guess the solution is to give up and restart Firefox and hope it works. Must be some convoluted example of a [heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Heisenbug).

**Edit:** It's the theme. When I use a theme or Firefox persona, the bookmarks toolbar will automatically set itself as the bottom-most toolbar. When I use the default FF4 skin, the toolbar goes back into position. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

The "Bookmarks Toolbar" refers to two different things.  It is a container bar, like the Navigation Bar, and it is also the "icon" for the object that displays your bookmarks.

You can put the bookmarks-object on another bar, and other things on the "Bookmarks Toolbar" thought I believe the menus must stay on the Menu Bar.

I hope this is useful in implementing the layout you want, and it may also clear up a possible misunderstanding.